# How to clean sound data on Parse.com?

Tags: audio, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

On Parse.com, in a Class I have one column which is AUDIO data.
My question is:
Does the AUDIO data gets completely removed automatically when I delete the ROW (using a Cloud function)?
Or do I need to do something special (before or after) to clean off the AUDIO data?

To make the context clearer here is the kind of code I use to upload the sound data:

```
    PFFile *parse_Sound;
    NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    parse_Sound = [PFFile fileWithName:@"VOICE"
                                  data:soundData];
    [parse_Sound saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        ……….
    }];
```

and later:

```
    parse_Object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PeraSentence"];
    [parse_Object setObject:parse_Sound forKey:@"AUDIO"];
    ………
```

Comment: What is your audio data ? It's a media file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a row, the files are not deleted. You need to go in Settings > General and click to "Clean Up Files" button.

All files are not referred by pointer in your database are removed.

> As you know, files can be referenced to from file-type columns in your
>   objects. They can be pointed to in this manner by one or many
>   different objects, and so they are not deleted automatically when any
>   of the objects that refer to them are deleted. The Clean Up job will
>   delete any files that have no such references to them.
>
> As a safeguard, any files uploaded in the previous hour won't be
>   deleted, regardless of how many objects point to them. This provides a
>   grace period to avoid deleting a file that was recently uploaded but
>   your app has not added a reference to it.
>
> This Clean Up job should be used carefully. If your app is not using
>   the file-type column to refer to files, and instead is copying the CDN
>   URL to a string-type column, this will not count as a reference and
>   the file will be deleted if it has no other file-type pointers to it.

Source: https://parse.com/questions/clean-up-files

Comment: Thanks, I did a clean up. Unfortunately the mail sent after that is not very useful. It only tells me that xxx files were removed for a total of yyy MB.
There is no way for me to see what has been deleted, for example to check that I did not made a mistake. I can only use my imagination to guess what (old data) may have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you stored it in Parse. If you stored it as data in a column then it lives and dies with the row. Delete the row you delete the data.

If instead you used a Parse File then your row only contains a pointer to the file, delete the row and you delete the pointer, but the file is still there. Same concept as pointers to other records.

Comment: See the update I made on the question. I think I am not using a Parse File (or all the files would have the same name: VOICE). Though not 100% sure and in case I am using such a file I don't know where to locate it on the server.

Comment: Every single file can have the same name, that's OK. Parse uses funky prefixes to give them unique URLs, the "name" is actually just a property you get/set and it gets appended to the name they give the file. Parse it also handling storage for you, you just set it and get it as you have done.